# which log operations are involved in this formula?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponentiation

I've a [function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tzbdtwxgix?lang=it) f1(x) that "scale" (not sure how to call it) a power of 2 function, such as:

[image]

[image]

Now, from this value, I display the dB measure (in the form `log10(x) * 20`; usually used for [audio and stuff](http://www.playdotsound.com/portfolio-item/decibel-db-to-float-value-calculator-making-sense-of-linear-values-in-audio-tools/)):

The fact is: it works if I also multiply it for `a` (i.e. `log10(x) * 20 * a`). If I remove it, the output is wrong (i.e. 6db for each twice).

Not sure the operations that simply permit to return correctly the result multipling by `a`.

Any smart log's operations involved which I don't see?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean why does $\log_{10}(t) = \frac{\ln(t)}{\ln(10)}$? If *yes*, then it's a property of logarithm, known as **Base Change Rule**.  See more about it on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/change-of-base-formula/).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Yooo : no, I don't understand why I need su also use "* a" display the correct dB after scaling the original power of 2. i.e. why once do "^ a" I need to do "* a"?

Comment: sorry, I can't help much as the question is unclear to me.

Comment: @Yooo try look at i var. Move the a slider. The results are keep on f2 only if you multiply by "a". If you remove that, the results differs... i.e. it compensate the Power of 1/a in some way. How?

Comment: I also do not understand the question.  Are you asking if/why $$(2^x)^{1/a} = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(10)}20a?$$

Comment: @XanderHenderson take the example of using f1(x) = 2^x. With x = 1, log10(f1) * 20 is exactly 6db (as expected). Now if I do f(x) = (2^x)^1/a, and use x=1 and a=2, I need to multiply "log10(f1) * 20" and "a" to get the same 6db. Why? How "^ 1/a" is related to " * a"? It seems that multiply by a outside the log(f1) is the same of log(f1^a)

Comment: I still do not understand your question.  It might also be worth noting that you have input a function $f_2$ which depends on a variable $x$, but the only variable in the definition of that function is $t$.  This is almost certainly causing nonsense results.

Comment: @XanderHenderson is correct to state that log10(x^a) = log10(x)*a? If so, for which property?

Comment: It is correct, but I am not sure what you mean by "for which property".  A property of logarithms is that $\log(a^b) = b\log(a)$, where $\log$ is a logarithm with any base, $a$ is a positive real number, and $b$ is any real number.  A quick Google search for "[properties of logarithms](https://www.google.com/search?q=properties+of+logarithms&oq=properties+of+logarithms)" gives many useful results.

Comment: "It seems that multiply by a outside the log(f1) is the same of log(f1^a) "..... Of course, it is.  That's a *fundamental* property of logs.  $m \log_k w = \log_k (w^m)$.  That is perhaps the second most basic fact about logarithms.

Comment: If $\log_b a = k$ then $b^k = a$ so $b^{kw}=a^w$ so $\log_b a^w = kw=w\log_b a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the "trick" here is that $\log(x^{a}) = a\log(x)$.